# 'The specified persistent store was not found.' error in CoreData

Tags: core-data, migration, datamodel

I'm getting this error: 
The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (Cocoa error 134140.)
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The specified persistent store was not found.'

I just changed to a new version of my data model. However if I activate the previous version of the data model, then the app works fine. If I activate the new version, I get that error. The only change that I made was that I made all the variables non-optional in my data model, which should be able to be handled by the automatic migration feature. I don't understand why it says it cannot find the persistent store, when there is no error thrown by [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:myPathDocs error:&error].

I seem to think this has something to do with the fact that the sqlite file in my main bundle is from the old version of the data model, but there is no sqlite file there that comes from the new version. However, I was under the impression that automatic migration would simply generate a new file for the new model on its own (?) and migrate the data from the existing file into it. Is this wrong?

In my iOS app, I have a file called Formats.sqlite that's in my Resources. At startup after a clean install the app looks to see if there's an existing Formats.sqlite in the app's /Documents folder. If there's not, it copies the one from its main bundle into there. This was all working fine before I made the new version of my model. Here is the code I use for that:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    int count = [[persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores] count];
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil && count) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Formats.sqlite"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:myPathDocs]) {
        NSLog(@"SQLite file not found, copying SQLITE file");
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Formats" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            if(![fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:myPathDocs error:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Error copying file at defaultStorePath to the documents path: %@",error);
            }
        }
    }
    storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, 
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, 
                             nil];
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator == nil) {
        persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    }
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
    {//my error code here}
```

So then the error gets thrown where it says "my error code here." What do I do in order to fix this? Why is this happening? Incidentally the console spits out all the steps for the migration, so it looks like it's trying to do it, but then it can't find the persistent store, which I don't understand why it can't find it, since it's been added in the build targets.

I just want to make sure that if people upgrade from previous versions of the app, their data gets migrated over and they don't have to re-enter everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the source of the error, I used this code to get the most detailed description of the error from the debugger:

```
    NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
    if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0) {
        for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors) {
            NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"  %@", [error userInfo]);
    }
```

Then after using that code, the error message said that one of the properties in my model did not have a default value, and that it would need one for the automatic migration to work correctly. After I added the default value for that property, then everything worked.

The above code snippet is very useful for debugging Core Data errors because without it, Core Data won't necessarily tell you which exact property in your model is the source of the problem. Using the "detailedError" code gave me the exact info I needed. **Thanks, "detailedError."**

Comment: Thanks. I was having this problem and I read this. It saved me. Then I realized I was who wrote it. Ahem.